# Como hacer un script en bash para extraer la vesión de un archivo tar.gz

Tags: bash, script, sed, grep, tar

tengo una consulta, deseo obtener la versión de un comprimido 'tar.gz' (current_program-latest.tar.gz), y enviarlo a un archivo llamado versión para seguir con el script, el interior del comprimido 'tar.gz' esta distribuido de esta forma:

```
-> current_program.tar.gz
   -> current_program.2.2.2/direcotry/directory2/directory3/files
   -> current_program.2.2.2/direcotry/directory2/directory3
   -> current_program.2.2.2/direcotry/directory2/files
   -> current_program.2.2.2/direcotry/directory2
   -> current_program.2.2.2/direcotry/version
   -> current_program.2.2.2/version
```

Entonces hay dos archivos `version` en dos archivos directorios distintos, ya he probado descargando otras versiones anteriores y todas tienen los mismos archivos, entonces agregue esto en el script:

```
tar -tf current_program-latest.tar.gz | grep version | cat > 1 && tr -d "curentpogamvsi/-_" < 1 > 2 | tail -n +2 2 > version
```

Este comando hace lo siguiente `tar -tf | grep | cat` obtienen los archivos con nombre version y los envia al archivo `1`, `tr -d elimina los caracteres innecesarios y envía` 2.2.2`al archivo`2`, por último` tail -2`elimina la primera linea y envía el resultado al archivo`version`

Este sería el extracto del script:

```
get(){
        ...
        local URL="https://current.abc"        
        local _WGET="which wget"
        local _CAT="which cat"
        local _TAR="which tar"
        local _GREP="which grep"
        local _GPG="which gpg"
        local NAME="current_version"
        local LATEST="latset.tar.gz"
        local WGET_CMD="$(${_WGET})"
        local CAT_CMD="$(${_CAT})"
        local TAR_CMD="$(${_TAR})"
        local GREP_CMD="$(${_GREP})"
        local GPG_CMD="$(${_GPG} --verify)"
        local VERSION="$($CAT_CMD /path/version | ${GREP_CMD}grep [0-9].[0-9].[0-9])"
        ${WGET_CMD} ${URL}/${NAME}-${LATEST}
        ${TAR_CMD} -tf ${NAME}-${LATEST} | ${GREP} version | ${CAT} > 1 && tr -d "curentpogam/-_" < 1 > 2 | tail -n +2 2 > version
        ${WGET_CMD} ${URL}/${NAME}-${LATEST}.sig
        ${GPG_CMD} ${NAME}${VERSION}.tar.gz.sig ${NAME}-${LATEST}
        ${TAR_CMD} xzf ${NAME}-{$LATEST}
        rm -rf 1 2
        ...
}
```

Todo está hecho con variables porque reutilizo las mismas sentencias y para usar los comandos uso `wich` para encontrarlos, porque trabajo con varios servidores ***FreeBSD*** y un servidor ***Linux***, en la variable `VERSION` obtengo el número de version con `cat | grep`, para posteriormente usarlos dentro del script como en `gpg` que sirve para verificar las firmas digitales del paquete, y uso `rm -rf` para eliminar los archivos temporales creados, como podrán entender la versión será usada en más partes del script, pero esto es lo más importante.
¿Como puedo mejorar el código en especial para no tener archivos temporales ni el último archivo `version` creado con tail? y si eso no es posible hacer eso ¿como puedo mantener solo la última línea ya que hay paquetes que pueden contener mas archivos `version`?

Y gracias @Juan Carlos Guibovich por tus consejos de como escribir la pregunta.

Comment: No entiendo una cosa: '...para seguir con el script..." se entiende que esa linea se encuentra en un script bash? Lo otro es porque el tail es a partir de la segunda linea si supuestamente ya filtraste? El comando puede mejorarse pero quisiera saber si solo el script contendrá esa linea o es parte de un script mas grande que luego se lee en el script. Puedes poner un  ejemplo de como es el archivo por dentro

Comment: Después de la actualización sigue sin verse claramente cuál es la intención... quieres convertir eso en una función del script o es otra cosa?

Comment: Lo que queria conocer es como es el formato del nombre de los archivos contenidos en el tar solo para los que contengan versión, por lo que pones parece ser ; `currentprogram_version-1.2` ...

Comment: y esto estará agregada a la utilidad cron, y si algún servidor falla por una actualización me llegará un mensaje y solo debo checar el paquete que tiene el inconveniente y no estar revisando el sistema completo

Comment: Juan Carlos estas en lo correcto las versiones tienen puntos y números

Comment: Para ver si es lo que entiendo, con esta linea `tar -t currentprogram_version* -f current_program-latest.tar.gz | awk -F_ '{print $2}'  obtiene la lista de archivos contenidos en el tar que comiencen por `currentprogram_version` luego  utilizando `awk` extraigo la segunda parte. No sé si eso quieres, por eso, te preguntaba cual eta el formato del nombre de los archivos que quieres extraer.

Comment: Ok, ahora entiendo que quieres hacer! Estaría genial si editases la pregunta y añadieses esta info allí. Por cierto  si usas `@yandri` (usando el nombre del usuario) notificas al susodicho  usuario y así sabe que le dejaste un mensaje y no tiene que estar revisando. Por otro lado, has planteado que sucede si se instala pero no funciona correctamente?

Comment: Para complementar de todas las versiones que están en ese archivo quienes sacar la penultima versión?

Comment: ok. Me parecio que estaba en el mismo nombre de archivo. Hice una pruebas con archivos vacios por eso pensé que el cat estaba demás. jeje Voy a revisar nuevamente

Comment: Disculpa, estaba en lo correcto, el `cat` no te muestra el contenido del archivo sino te pinta el resultado del `pipe` por eso fue la consulta  referida a como es el formato de nombre del archivo que están en el tar. En la anterior me diste a entender que los archivos se llamaban `version` y por eso es que hacias el `cat` entendiendo que el cat mostraba el contenido de `versión` pero no es así. Veo que has hecho una actualización pero igual el `cat` del `tar` esta demás porque con el grep te da el mismo resultado. Aparte que no lo podría abrir porque está en el zip.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, No mejoré el código solo lo hice como lo tengo originalmente

Comment: Intenté responder, pero es difícil estar seguro sin un ejemplo. Fíjate que `'[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]'` fallara con versión `3.10.2` o cualquier otra que tenga números >10. Probablemente quieres algo como `grep '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*`.

Answer (score 3):

No hace falta ningun archivo temporal. De hecho, tampoco hace falta el `cat`, ni en `commando | cat > archivo` ni en `cat archivo | grep`. Puedes directamente hacer `commando > archivo` o `grep archivo`. Bueno, en lo de tu pregunta específica, podrías hacer algo así como:

```
get(){
        ...
        local url="https://current.abc"        
        local wget_cmd=$(which wget)
        local cat_cmd=$(which cat)
        local tar_cmd=$(which tar)
        local grep_cmd=$(which grep)
        local gpg_cmd=$(which gpg)
        local name="current_version"
        local latest="latest.tar.gz"
        version="$( $grep_cmd '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' /path/version)"

        "$wget_cmd" "$url/${name}-${latest}"
        "$tar_cmd" -tf "${name}-${latest}" | 
            "$grep" version | tr -d "curentpogam/-_" | tail -n +2 > version
        "$wget_cmd" "$url/${name}=${latest}.sig"
        "$gpg_cmd"  --verify "$name$version.tar.gz.sig" "${name}-${latest}"
        "$tar_cmd" xzf "${name}-${latest}"
}
```

He cambiado los nombres de variables para no usar mayúsculas, ya que por convenio las mayúsculas se usan para variables del sistema y en general es mejor evitar usarlas para variables en tus scripts porque puedes tener colisiones que causan bugs muy difíciles de entender.

Quizás lo más importante es que he puesto todos tus variables entre comillas. ¡Esto es *esencial*! Para más (mucha, mucha más) información que nunca quisiste saber sobre el asunto, mira a: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222). Básicamente, siempre quieres tenerlos entre comillas.

Después, te quité el uso excesivo de `${var}` ya que no es necesario a menos que tengas que usar dos variables pegadas y bash no tendría manera de saber dónde acaba un nombre de variable y empieza el otro como en `${name}-${version}`, donde `$name-$version` sería interpretado como `$name-` y `$version`.

También quité lo `_comando` y `comando=${_comando}` ya que no sirve para nada. El `which` no es mágico, simplemente busca en los directorios de tu `PATH` algún ejecutable con este nombre. Si funciona el `which`, ya tienes el ejecutable y no ganas nada teniendo dos pasos. No veo para qué quieres el `which`, pero ya lo veremos más tarde.

Finalmente, también cambié los comandos, quitando el `cat` que no hace falta y los archivos temporales que tampoco son necesarios, y cambié tu expresión regular para que funcione con versiones `>9` y encuentra los `.` correctamente.

Como dije antes, no entiendo por qué quieres el `which`. Ya que el `which` simplemente busca ejecutables en el `PATH`, no ganas absolutamente nada en buscar su dirección completa: por definición, si `which commando` funciona, entonces también funcionará `commando` solo. Y, si `commando` solo no funciona, pues tampoco funcionará `which comando`. Entonces, yo haría simplemente esto:

```
get(){
        ...
        local version="$(grep '[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*' /path/version)"
        wget "$url/${name}-${latest}"
        tar -tf "${name}-${latest}" | grep version |
          tr -d "curentpogam/-_" | tail -n +2 > version
        wget "$url/${name}=${latest}.sig"
        gpg --verify "${name}${version}.tar.gz.sig" "${name}-${latest}"
        tar xzf "${name}-${latest}"
}
```

Comment: Me parece que hasta el `grep version`  estaría demás si es que se pone como parte del parámetro -t del `tar`:   `tar -t *version* -f  "${name}-${latest}" |  tr -d "curentpogam/-_" | tail -n +2 > version`

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich sip. En Linux (es decir con GNU grep) podrías también hacer simplemente: `tar -tf current_program.tar.gz | grep -oP '\d+[\d.]+(?=/version)' > version` y de manera mas portable `tar -tf current_program.tar.gz | sed -En 's|^[^.]+\.([0-9.]+)/version.*|\1|p' > version`. Pero como no estoy seguro de los datos de entrada, quise quedarme mas cerca al original de la cuestión.

Comment: lo probé en consola y funciona perfecto pero el inconveniente es que dentro del script no funciona

Comment: @yandri lo mejor sería hacer una nueva pregunta, mostrando el script, como llamas la función, y que pasa. Si puedes, simplifica el script y danos solo lo más mínimo que reproduzca el error.

Comment: El error que me presenta con el comando de la respuesta, es el mismo que me presentaba al inicio con un comando más corto, esa fue la razón por la que lo alargue haciendo el archivo 1 y 2, ahí es que hice la pregunta para ver si alguien podía mejorarlo, pero al parecer solo están probando en la consola y no dentro de un script, vea por donde lo vea el mio es funcional y es mejor dejarlo así porque estoy perdiendo el tiempo probando métodos que no resultan, de todas formas gracias por la ayuda muchos de sus comentarios me despejaron de varias dudas.

Comment: Y para sacarles de la duda sobre el error ` tar ` no admite ` | ` si no es exportado a un archivo por esa razón usé ` cat ` .

Comment: el `|` no lo manejo el  `tar` sino el shell, debes tener por ahi un peqqueño error de sintaxis. salvo que el `|` este delante del `tar`

Comment: como dije antes mi código original funciona bien, solo quería mejorarlo, si se dan cuenta lo único que cambia es que mi código genera 3 archivos cuando solo debe generar 1, y en eso quería que me ayuden pero no se pudo

Comment: @Yandri es dificil ayudarte con un error que no compartes. ¿Que error te da? Yo prové con un tgz conteniendo ficheros con los mismos nombres que tu pregunta, y no me dio ningún error. Lo que dices sobre el `tar` y el `|` me hace pensar que tienes un error de sintaxis como dijo Juan Carlos ya que el `tar` nunca ve el `|`, eso lo maneja el shell.

Comment: @1 bueno ahí voy a dejar otra pregunta para que revisen como esta el script y junto con un link de descarga